# Save multiple image into mysql php from android but only one image get inserted

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, android-listview

I have three list view in Activity A as below

[image]

When the submit `button` is clicked, the text and image path will be saved into `MySQL` and the `image` will be stored in `PhotoUpload` folder.

I'm able to stored 3 text into MySQL but the problem is only one path of the image is saved into MySQL . Between, the image suppose to save inside PhotoUpload but it just save outside the folder !

It totally frustrating !

**Activity A**

```
  public void uploadImageAndText(ArrayList<ImageAndText> listItems, final String id) { // Assume id holds value 2 (ts_id)
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    String type = i.getType();
                    String[] Type = type.split(":");
                    object.put("type", Type[1]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Type[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String amount = i.getAmount();
                    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
                    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
                    String description = i.getDescription();
                    String[] Description = description.split(":");
                    object.put("description", Description[1]);
                    Uri uploadImage = i.getImage();
                    Log.e("Image",uploadImage+"");
                    object.put("image", uploadImage.toString());
                    object.put("ts_id", id);
                    jsonArray.put(object);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AddStaff ru = new AddStaff(jsonArray);
            ru.execute();

        }

        class AddStaff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            AddStaff(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddClaims.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
                        String strUri = jsonObject.getString("image");
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                        data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE, getStringImage(Uri.parse(strUri)));
                        Log.e("AAA",jsonArray.toString());
                        Log.e("String",getStringImage(Uri.parse(strUri)));
                        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                        String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                        return result;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        public String getStringImage(Uri imgUri) {

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                return encodedImage;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
```

**staffBenefit.php**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";

            $image = $_POST['image'];

            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";

            $id=1;

            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

            $path=time()."$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";

            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
                echo 'Error saving image';  
            }

            if ( $stmt && $bytes) {
                 foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();
                    if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

I check the image path and three of them are the same ! And only one image(2.png) saved, and it is outside the PhotoUpload, not inside :(

> path problem ? java problem ? or php problem ???

**Edited(php)**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";


            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";

            $id=1;

            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;



            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'UploadPhoto', '' );
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 
            $path=time()."$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";
            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $item['image'] ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
            echo 'Error saving image';  
             }else{
             $stmt->bind_param('sssss', 
            $item['type'], 
            $item['amount'], 
            $item['description'], 
            $actualpath, 
            $item['ts_id'] );
           $res=$stmt->execute();
        if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
    }
} 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }

?>
```

Path

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\CRUD\UploadPhoto
```

Comment: I'm confused.. a) you upload 1 image and it will reference this in 3 separate rows in the database? b) or, you upload 3 images and you want there to be 3 separate for each image?

Comment: @ChrisBanks I have 3 list in my listView. When submit button clicked, they suppose to be saved into MySQL. I upload 3 images but only one image path and image(first image) get saved

Comment: @Tony: all images is uploaded in PhotoUpload  folder or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no...I saw 2.png only and it is outside the folder

Comment: @Tony what are you selecting

Comment: @meda i didn't select anything, I just want to insert

Comment: @Tony `SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: @meda I follow [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-using-php-mysql-android-studio/), the different is I store them using arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are overwriting the image data in you `doInBackground` loop.

Second the PHP upload code is not in the loop

**JAVA**

You should have only one loop, when you build your JSON, put everything you need there

```
for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    
    String type = i.getType();
    String[] Type = type.split(":");
    String amount = i.getAmount();
    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
    String description = i.getDescription();
    String[] Description = description.split(":");
    
    //Image
    String image = i.getImage().toString()
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(image);
    
    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
    object.put("type", Type[1]);
    object.put("description", Description[1]);
    object.put("ts_id", id);
    object.put("image", image);
    object.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE, getStringImage(imageUri));
    
    jsonArray.put(object);
}
```

Then put the `JSON` in your `hashmap` to send

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
        
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
        String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

**PHP**

The php would change, you won't need `$image = $_POST['image'];`

You will get the image data from the json `$listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true );`

You would put the upload code in the loop , and insert only on successful upload

```
foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 
    $path= microtime()."$id.png";
    $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";
    $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $item['image'] ) );
    if( !$bytes ){
        echo 'Error saving image';  
    }else{
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', 
        $item['type'], 
        $item['amount'], 
        $item['description'], 
        $actualpath, 
        $item['ts_id'] );
        $res=$stmt->execute();
        if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

**Full PHP script**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){
            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 
            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";
            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` 
                 ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) 
                  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql )){
                $url="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/";
                foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 
                    $image_name = microtime().".png";
                    $save_path = 'PhotoUpload/'.$image_name;
                    $image_url = $url.$image_name;
                    $bytes=file_put_contents($save_path, base64_decode($item['image']));
                    if( !$bytes ){
                        echo 'Error saving image';  
                    }else{
                        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', 
                        $item['type'], 
                        $item['amount'], 
                        $item['description'], 
                        $image_url, 
                        $item['ts_id'] );
                        if( !$res=$stmt->execute()){ 
                            echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I still getting the same result and only the last image get inserted.The image just stored outside the folder

Comment: @Tony `Log.d("log", "json = " + jsonArray.toString());`  what do you see?

Comment: `D/log﹕ json = [{"amount":" ","image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH\/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH\/wAARCAUAAtADASIA\nAhEBAxEB\/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA\nAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3\nODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm\n`

Comment: I can see the image in the folder now, but only one image get saved, and it named 1452823734...

Comment: @Tony i want to see ur full json produced by the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100777/discussion-between-meda-and-tony).